# Unslider displaying weird width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, unslider

I have been using Unslider to make a slider for my website and I am running Foundation 5 as the framework.

Unslider doesn't seem to display properly, I can't post an image, but you can see it underneath the Twitter logo.

[Website](http://theforestschool.academy/new)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
class="banner" you can add `width:132px;` and `margin-left: 200px;`
```

this is Your css Code you must add two css file   `width:132px;` and `margin-left: 200px;`

```
 overflow: hidden;
    width: 132px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 200px;
```